# How to automatically position window like Popup?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I created virtual keyboard implemented as custom control inhereted from `Window`. I want to know if there is a way to automatically position keyboard near `TextBox` like it does `Popup` when it's `PopupPlacement` property wasn't set. Or I should implement my custom algorithm?

**UPDATE:**
I need to move my virtual keyboard from one `TextBox` to another and position it **near** **TextBox** so that it fits into the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented custom algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.aspx) class - it has an [PlacementTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget.aspx) property to allow you to lock it to specific UIElement. I think you should be able to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: But how can I find absolute child window coordinates relative to screen using this solution considering child window size?

Comment: @JohnKZ You shouldn't need that. Just bind the ToolTip's PlacementTarget to the TextBox: `PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBoxName}"`

Comment: And then I need to integrated my window inside Tooltip?

Comment: @JohnKZ Make the keyboard a UserControl (it is pretty much the same as Window - just change the base type and root tag and it should work :) ).